# Reference object Web SQL JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, local-storage, web-sql

Check my code:

```
function callQuery(){
  db.transaction(function querySum(tx){
    tx.executeSql('SELECT SUM (entry) FROM ENTRIES',[], getNum, errorCB);
  });
}

function getNum(tx, results){
  len = results.rows.length;        
  for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
    items = results.rows.item(i);

    console.log(items);
    document.querySelector('#sum').innerHTML += items;
  }
}
```

The output is: `Object {SUM (entry): 459}` and `innerHTML` is `[object Object]`.

How can I reference it? Do I have to store the SUM in another table to reference it?

Comment: What exactly do you want to reference? Judging from the output, you can refer to the result by `items['SUM (entry)']`.

Comment: Yeah, I want to output the query result which is 459. Using items['SUM(entry)'] returns undefined...

Comment: `SUM (entry)`, with whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a name like so:

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT SUM(entry) AS total FROM ENTRIES',[], getNum, errorCB);
```

So you will have **total** that you can use afterwards.